# C++ Library for implementing a web services api over legacy code?

Tags: c++, web-services, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, wsdl

Does anyone know of any really good C++ Libraries for implementing a web services api over top of existing legacy code?

I've got two portions that are in need of it:

- An old-school client/server api (No, not web based, that's the problem)
- An old cgi application that it integrates with the client and server.

Let me know if you've had any luck in the past implementing something like this using the library.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has put out [native code webservices API (WWSAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/network/ee532085.aspx) that looks pretty decent.  I haven't had a chance to use it yet.  We had originally ignored it, since it required Windows 7 or Server 2008, but they've finally released a runtime library for older OSs.

I would advise staying away from Microsoft's old SOAP SDK.  For one, it's been deprecated; two, it's not terribly easy to distribute; and three, it's terrible to code for compared to the .NET offerings.

What we've done is written a bit of C++\CLI to interface our existing C++ codebase with .NETs webservice framework.  This turned out to be remarkably easy.  .NET will generate all the classes and boilerplate code you need based of of a WSDL file.  Then you just write some C++\CLI code to handle the incoming data as managed classes and fill in some managed classes as responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apache AXIS/C interface to build a web services interface.  It has plugins for Apache and IIS (and I think FastCGI), and lets you talk web services to your legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

I used gSOAP in a project and it was quite straightforward. Compared to Axis/C, I found it easier to learn and use. I never used POCO, can't give you an opinion, but it's gaining popularity recently. This is the link for gSOAP

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html